# Does ING bank V-Pay cards work on Budapest? And What budget needed for 3 days on Budapest?

Tags: budget, netherlands, hungary, budapest

I'm planning to visit Budapest. So, I have some points related to using cards, money and budget.

- Does V-Pay cards work on Budapest?
- How much money I need for 3 days (eating, drinking and visiting museums)?
- Does shops, restaurants and museums deal with Euro or only local currency?

Thanks and sorry as I included many points in one question.

```
Note: I add Netherlands tag as If someone has the same ING card and know the answer.
```

Comment: ING Poland and ING Netherlands function as separate entities. Connected, but not related when it comes to "can I do X in country Y". I assume this may be the case for other ones, too. You may want to be more specific which ING are you talking about.

Comment: I don't know about V-Pay and the second question highly depends on where you go exactly (and it's probably off-topic). As for currency: don't pay with EUR. It's possible in many places but always at terrible rates. Exchange/withdraw some HUF if you want cash, or just pay by card (as Eugen says, [Revolut](https://www.revolut.com/)/[Transferwise](https://transferwise.com/gb/borderless/) are great options if you travel or do online shopping a lot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about V-Pay (never heard of it), but the main card companies (Visa+Mastercard) are accepted at most places. The place I really need cash are street vendors and bakeries, but I don't carry much with me otherwise.

Don't use EUR! Even though restaurants and some shops accept it, they change at a terrible rate (like 250 HUF/EUR)! Even the infamous change at the airport is better than that. Anyway: if you arrive by plane, only change some for the taxi ride (700+300/km) or train/bus at the airport. In downtown, you'll get sensible rates ( https://correctchange.hu/ shows at the moment 317.1-319.4+tax ) so you won't lose much even if you have to change it back later. But you can use your card with probably similar rate (or the aforementioned Transferwise).

Eating: 1500-1800 HUF for a decent meal at a not too fancy restaurant. Of course, this will go up steeply if you sit in a fancy place or too touristy area (Vaci utca, or the castle). Price of drinks varies even more. If you know what you want to see, museums tend to have english web pages, with prices, so use it. ( e.g. 1600 HUF https://mnm.hu/en/entrance-ticket for Nemzeti Muzeum, 1800 for the permanent exhibition at Nemzeti Galeria https://en.mng.hu/tickets/ etc. ) Most museums are open on weekends, but closed on mondays (or some other day of the week), so be prepared, and make a different program if necessary. You can use your mobile data (EU roaming) without any additional charge, so do it.

There are some nice open places (the castle, Hosok tere, zoo, etc.), so the forecast might get handy. ( met.hu, koponyeg.hu )

Also, don't invite suspiciously friendly sluts for drinks, that might be a scam. (I've read about this a few years ago, and don't know if the police managed to solved it or not.)

Comment: Many Thanks for your useful information :)